# given an array for each element count how many divisibility

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of numbers, now I want to take a number from the list and check how many elements are there that can divide this number with the remainder as 0.

Here is my code:

```
public static void countDivibilies(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int e = list.get(i);
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            int k = list.get(j);
            if (e % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(e + " : " + count);
    }
}
```

For sample input:

```
2, 4, 8, 2
```

Output is:

```
2 : 2
4 : 3
8 : 4
2 : 2
```

But this code runs in `O(n2)` time complexity. But my input list size range is up to 10<sup>5</sup>, also each element is between 1 and 10<sup>5</sup>. So how can improve the time complexity of this program?

Comment: Well, usually if `2` has two potential dividors, and `2` is a dividor of `4`, I'd tend to say that it has an extra dividor than `2`. Hint: sort your list first

Comment: What is the maximum value of each element?

Comment: @iota, each element is also 10 power 5, I will update my question with it now

Comment: So this task isn't online somewhere, you made it up yourself? (That would also explain the name `countDivibilies` :-)

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a frequency `Map` in `O(N)` time from the `List`.
2. Calculate divisors of each element of the `List` in `O(sqrt(N))` time. Use the frequency `Map` to find how many divisors of the element are in the `List`. The total time complexity is `O(Nsqrt(N))`.

```
public static void countDivibilies(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> freq = list.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1, Integer::sum));
    for(int x : list){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i * i <= x; i++){
            if(x % i == 0) {
                count += freq.getOrDefault(i, 0);
                if(x / i != i) //don't overcount square root
                   count += freq.getOrDefault(x / i, 0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x + " : " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why we are running internal loop from i =1? Also the if conditions `if(x % i == 0) {` and `if(x / i != i)` and the way we are incrementing count

Comment: @learner We are finding the divisors of the number. Each time we find one, we increase the count by the number of times that divisor appears in the list.

Comment: What is your N?

Comment: @Manuel The maximum of the size of the list and the maximum element.

Answer (score 0):

C++ code-

```
void countDivisibilities(vector<int> list) {
unordered_map<int, int> freq;
for (int x : list) freq[x]++;
for (int x : list) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i * i <= x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            count += freq[i];
            if (x / i != i) //don't overcount square root
                count += freq[x / i];
        }
    }
    cout << x << " : " << count << endl;
}
```

}